# How to return the last record in a table with multiple states

Tags: sql

The following SQL query will return all my programs that are in development or completed mode. The goal here is to get the latest state of all programs.

I use the following query to return all my program states

```
SELECT PK_ProgramState, FK_Program, State
FROM ProgramStates
```

I get the following results:

[image: Program states]

As seen by the yellow highlight in the colored rectangles of this image, I want those "FK_Program" records to be returned. The others who come before the last highlighted record state are not needed.

I can't seem to figure out how to do it ... All the queries I've been trying give me bogus results. All help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.PK_ProgramStatee, s1.FK_Program, s1.State
FROM ProgramStates s1
inner join
(
  SELECT max(PK_ProgramState) as mstate, FK_Program
  FROM ProgramStates
  group by FK_Program
) s2 on s2.mstate = s1.PK_ProgramState and s2.FK_Program = s1.FK_Program
```

Comment: I get the error: `Column 'ProgramStates.FK_Program' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
select fk_program
from ProgramStates ps
group by fk_program
having substring_index(group_concat(State order by PK_ProgramState desc), ',', 1
                      ) in ('Development', 'Completed');
```

This is finding the last state using `group_concat()` than then comparing it to the states that you want to look for.

You could also write the `having` clause as:

```
having group_concat(State order by PK_ProgramState desc) like 'Completed%' or
       group_concat(State order by PK_ProgramState desc) like 'Development%'
```

The intention might be clearer in this form.

Comment: I get the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.` On the first "group_concat" line

Comment: @Alex . . . The `order by` is definitely part of the `group_concat()` syntax (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html).  Can you edit your question and add in the query that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FK_Program, 
    (SELECT TOP(1) State FROM ProgramStates P1 
    WHERE P1.FK_Program = ProgramStates.FK_Program 
    ORDER BY PK_ProgramState DESC) as State
FROM ProgramStates
```

Comment: @Alex are you using MSSQL or MySQL?

Comment: If you are using MSSQL remove the LIMIT 1 and change SELECT State to SELECT TOP(1) State

Comment: Updated to refelct MSSQL. I saw the MySQL tag on the question so I assumed that's what you were using.

Comment: My apologies! I updated the tags. Juergen d was slightly faster so I'll have to accept his answer but yours worked so I +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.fk, (select ps.state from ProgramStates ps
              where ps.FK_Program = p.fk
              order by ps.PK_ProgramState desc limit 1)

from (select distinct q.FK_Program as fk
from ProgramStates q) as p
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/422d92/19

Answer (score 1):

```
    select 
    ps.PK_ProgramState, 
    ps.FK_Program,
    ps.state
from 
    ProgramStates ps
inner join

    (select max(PK_ProgramState)PK_ProgramState, FK_Program from ProgramStates  group by FK_Program) stg
    on stg.FK_Program=ps.FK_Program and stg.PK_ProgramState=ps.PK_ProgramState
```